# Line is not perfectly horizontal in Commutative Diagram in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, commutative-diagrams

I ran into an issue today, while rendering a simple diagram with Tikz. The horizontal line in the following picture is ever so slightly lower on the right hand side than on its left.
[image: Commutative Diagram]

Adding a subscript to the `\mathbb B` on the left didn't change this behavior - neither did omitting the label `h_j` on the top.

Here is a minimal working code for this diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) 
[matrix of math nodes,row sep=4em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em] 
{
\mathbb B & \mathbb B_{j} \\
          & \mathbb B_{i} \\ 
}; 
\path[-stealth] 
(m-1-1) edge node [above] {$h_{j}$} (m-1-2)
        edge node [below] {$h_{i}$} (m-2-2)
(m-1-2) edge node [right] {$h_{\mathbb B_{i}, \mathbb B_{j}}$} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Is this a known issue and does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `\mathbb{B}_j` on the right is deeper than the `\mathbb{B}` on the left, that is why the line is lower on the right. You can just add a `\vphantom{_j}` to the node on the left to compensate for this.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) 
[matrix of math nodes,row sep=4em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em] 
{
\mathbb{B}\vphantom{_j} & \mathbb{B}_j \\
          & \mathbb B_{i} \\ 
}; 
\path[-stealth] 
(m-1-1) edge node [above] {$h_{j}$} (m-1-2)
        edge node [below] {$h_{i}$} (m-2-2)
(m-1-2) edge node [right] {$h_{\mathbb B_{i}, \mathbb B_{j}}$} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also with node `positioning` instead of `\matrix` can look nicer:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
\node (b) {$\mathbb{B}$};
\node[right=of b]  (bj) {$\mathbb{B}_j$};
\node[below=of bj] (bi) {$\mathbb{B}_i$};   

\path[-stealth] 
    (b)  edge node [above] {$h_{j}$} (bj)
         edge node [below] {$h_{i}$} (bi)
    (bj) edge node [right] {$h_{\mathbb B_{i}, \mathbb B_{j}}$} (bi);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. It's apparently the 'j' that messes things up. I suspected something like this and in my troubleshooting, I added an '_{k}' to the B on the left - in this case, however, the issue remains. Good to know and thanks again.

Comment: @Stefan Different letters have different depth/height, so using `_{k}` need not be equivalent to using `_{j}`.

Answer (score 11):

I suggest using [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd?lang=en):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\mathbb{B} \arrow[r,"h_j"] \arrow[dr,swap,"h_i"] &
  \mathbb{B}_j \arrow[d,"h_{\mathbb{B}_i,\mathbb{B}_j}"]
\\
& \mathbb{B}_i
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to use `tikz-cd` to compensate the different text depth? Also, adding a little information on tikz-cd would be nice...

Comment: @Dux There is plenty of information on the site about `tikz-cd`; I know well this doesn't directly answers the question, but the syntax is way simpler than using `\matrix` *and* the depth problem is completely irrelevant. Adding `text depth=0.5pt` to every node is definitely not the solution, because some node could have much larger depth, think to a fraction.  I won't downvote your answer, though.

Comment: Thank you very much :) This is definitely a point that one could debate over, I like to create styles for the nodes in my picture that cover all their content. But this is just me ofc. I do not know much about `tikt-cd`, that's why I suggested a little input in your answer instead of just giving the name. Saves one visit to google ;)

Comment: In my next document, I will probably give tikz-cd a shot. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

As was already mentioned, the problem is the text depth of the content of your nodes. One simple way of adjusting this is to reserve equal space for this in every node by specifying the text depth manually using the key `text depth`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={text depth=0.5pt}
]

\matrix (m) 
[matrix of math nodes,row sep=4em,column sep=4em, minimum width=2em] 
{
\mathbb B & \mathbb B_{j} \\
          & \mathbb B_{i} \\ 
}; 
\path[-stealth] 
(m-1-1) edge node [above] {$h_{j}$} (m-1-2)
        edge node [below] {$h_{i}$} (m-2-2)
(m-1-2) edge node [right] {$h_{\mathbb B_{i}, \mathbb B_{j}}$} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tikz-cd` uses a custom rectangle shape named `asymmetrical rectangle` which has its vertical center at a fixed (but customizable) distance from the base line. This makes straight lines between nodes in the same row automatically perfectly horizontal. You can use it with a normal matrix/tikzpicture as well. Instead of `text depth=…` uses `asymmetrical rectangle`.

Answer (score 2):

[XYpic](https://tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/Xy-pic.html) provides another alternative.  It gets the alignment correct in this case without special adjustment.  The syntax is very similar to `tikz-cd` in simple cases.  (Although I think it would be more correct to say: the syntax of `tikz-cd` is very similar to `xymatrix`... )

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[matrix,pdf,arrow]{xy}
\begin{document}
\begin{xymatrix}{
  \mathbb{B} \ar[rd]_{h_i} \ar[r]^{h_j}
  &\mathbb{B}_j \ar[d]^{h_{\mathbb{B}_i,\mathbb{B}_j}}
\\
  &\mathbb{B}_i
\\}
\end{xymatrix}
\end{document}
```

[image]